# I have an element with position fixed to make it float - how can I prevent it floating when it reaches the footer?

Tags: css, footer

I want my floating sidebar to stop before it hits the footer - the only solutions I have found so far involve using javascript, but I'd prefer if there were a way to go without if possible!

a baisc example: [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/TWNej/9/)

By adding the code below, I can get it to stop, but it then pushes everything inside my sidebar way up the page:

```
bottom: 500px;
```

Comment: I'm afraid Javascript might be your best (and only) friend here, but I'm keen to see any interesting suggestions! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not exactly what you are looking for, because I can't think of any solutions that don't involve any JS

What you can do though - if you give the footer element a position (relative or absolute), the sidebar will slide down behind as the page scrolls.

```
 .footer
        {
            width: 100%;
            border: 1px solid green;
            height: 500px;
            background-color: green;
            position:relative;
        }
```

Comment: Thank you very much - this does the job well, and I'm not sure there is a better solution without javascript

Answer (score 0):

Ok, your problem is, you don't really understand HTML container bounding, and flow.

I would spend some time looking at HTML Flow tutorials, and understanding exactly whats happening, as it will make your life in the future much easier.

Another trick is to put borders around every containing structure such as DIV's, so that you can see how each of your objects are nested, etc...

The problem is, when you take and add bottom:500px;, you are absolutely positioning the footer, this automatically removes it from the normal HTML flow.  I am guessing your right toolbar is out of flow as well.

So instead of using absolute positioning on either the footer or the right side toolbar, you will need to use a bounding outer container that encapsulates the whole page, then place each element on the page in the order you want the flow, using float:left, float:right to get your vertical positioning.  As long as your footer is the last thing within your bounding container, and all elements are within the flow, and the width on the footer is set to 100%, you should get the behavior your looking for.